# Run javascript method in asp.net webforms method

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I want to show a javascript alert when a user changes a value in a select-box. This is my code, what am i doing wrong?

aspx

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGroups" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlWagons_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
```

aspx.cs

```
    protected void ddlWagons_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClientScriptManager script = Page.ClientScript;
        script.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "OpenWindowScript", "alert('Clicked')");
    }
```

Comment: I belive you can achieve this result by using jQuery.

Comment: I don't want to use jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

Add

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

to your designer part

and in code part add

```
var ID="Whatever the data is";
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "script", "alert('"+ID+"');", true);
```

If you are using update panel

try this

```
var ID="Whatever the data is";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "script", "alert('"+ID+"');", true);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to handle the `onchange` event before the postback occurs

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" onchange="alert('Clicked')" />
```

If you don't need a postback then don't use a server control.

Comment: I forgot to mention that i also want to call a javascript method when the backend method has completed, is this possible?

Comment: @TobiasOlofsson so you need the postback? Are you running something at the server-side and then need to callback into the client?

Comment: @TobiasOlofsson after back end code completes you can use `RegisterStartupScript` for adding a script.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGroups" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlWagons_SelectedIndexChanged" clientIdMode="static"></asp:DropDownList>
```

and in JS:

```
document.getElementById("ddlGroups").addEventListener("change", function(){
    alert("new value: " + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);
});
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that i also want to call a javascript method when the backend method has completed, is this possible?

Comment: You mean an alert? Have you looked into ajax calls?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: Have you used `clientIdMode="static"`?